# Detecting Mouse Events with JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am developing an on screen music keyboard using JavaFX under Kotlin.  The graphics and layout are in place using Buttons with appropriate images.  The buttons are added to a Group which is in a StacKPane.

I can detect simple mouse press and release events to trigger appropriate MIDI on/off messages.  To this point everything is working fine except that the keyboard is monophonic (IE only able to play a single note at a time).

I wish to extend the keyboard to play multiple notes.  The sequence of gesture are as follows:
Mouse press on an initial key triggers the first note.  If the mouse enters an adjacent key with the button down, the original note should continue while a new note is triggered.  Whenever the button is released or the mouse is no longer above any key, all notes should stop.

I have implemented something similar a decade ago using Swing but the JavaFX events do not operate the same way.

I can detect the initial mouse pressed event, however as long as the button is down, MouseEntered events are not detected when moving to another key.    I have also tried MouseMoved, MouseDraggedEnterd and DragDetected with no luck.  It is as if the initial MousePressed event is blocking all other events until the button is released.   Any suggestions?  Thanks

Code Snippet

```
 fun setKeyListeners(b: Button, keynumber: Int) {
      b.setOnMousePressed { _ ->
            node as VirtualKeyboard
            val velocity = 64
            node.triggerOn(keynumber, velocity)
            status("key: ${node.lastKeynumber} vel: ${node.lastVelocity}")
        }

        b.setOnMouseReleased { _ ->
            node as VirtualKeyboard
            node.triggerOff(keynumber)
        }

        // b.setOnMouseMoved { _ -> println("Moved $keynumber") }
        // b.setOnMouseDragged { _ -> println("Dragged $keynumber") }
        // b.setOnMouseEntered { _ -> println("Entered $keynumber") }
    }
```

Comment: did you try to run each note on a different thread ?

Comment: See the documentation of [`MouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html)  (specifically, the section titled "_Dragging gestures_") and [`MouseDragEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html).

Comment: Thanks.   Drag and Drop is the way to go.  Even though I am not doing a true drag and drop operation the mouse gestures mimic one.  One thing that threw me for a bit is the fact the Dragboard must have some content for the DnD operations to be recognized.  I just used an empty string.

Comment: for future questions: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You mention you went with drag-and-drop; may I ask why? As I understand it you aren't transferring data anywhere. There are three kinds of dragging gestures: 1) simple press-drag-release, 2) full press-drag-release, and 3) drag-and-drop. From your question I would have thought  option #2 would have better fit your needs.

Comment: Slaw you are correct.  I am not doing a true Drag and Drop. Your number 2 option more closely describes my implementation.